# getting a syntax error when trying to upload to my site

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, product-images, wysiwyg

I cannot upload product images, I cannot upload images in a cms block through the wysiwyg. 
I am getting this error:
[image]

I went ahead and replaced all of the .js files with the original download files, just in case I had somehow altered one, but this has not helped in the least. 
Can any body help me find a direction to diagnose where this issue is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

It seems some syntax error in your code. When you will get this error in console you will also able to see the line number on view source of page where you are getting this error so once you click on this link you will be able to see the actual code where you have syntax error 
you can see attach screenshot for your reference :
[image]

Comment: Screenshot is very difficult to view. Please attach more visible one.

Comment: This doesn't help me in anyway to address my issue. I have updated the code to be an image of what I get in the console.

Comment: I know it will not help you, but it will help us to understand more about your issue. Thanks.